# When uploading a file I get $_FILE['tmp_name'] as blank

Tags: php

I am uploading a file whose size is approx 20MB, below is the result of `print_r($_FILES)`:

```
  (
        [name] => 10k.csv
        [type] => 
        [tmp_name] => 
        [error] => 1
        [size] => 0
    )
```

I have also increased size of upload in php.ini to `upload_max_filesize=64M`. Then also unable to upload file. What points might I be missing?

Comment: Can we see your form? Have you set a filesize there?

Comment: What's the `post_max_size`  value in your `php.ini`?

Comment: No have not set filesize in upload form...though i have enhanced upload size in php.ini also i would request you to help me in what is the difference in enhancing filesize in form and in upload size through ini

Comment: Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Comment: `post_max_size` needs to be  >=  `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: yes i did what is in  this.

Comment: post_max_size needs to be >= upload_max_filesize  done still getting same(
            [name] => 10k.csv
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

Comment: are you reloading the `php.ini` when you make changes?

Answer (score 2):

The `[error] => 1` line is telling you there was an error with your upload.

The PHP "Error Messages Explained" documentation says the following...

> Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

You need to increase the upload_max_filesize.

You can set the upload_max_filesize in PHP.INI or by adding the following to your .htaccess file.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
php_value post_max_size 30M
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Just to append: Make sure you reload the `php.ini` file when you make changes

Comment: trying to reload but getting error reload: Unknown job: php.ini while doing...reload php.ini

Comment: Can you upload smaller files, maybe a text file? Have you restarted Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` to 64M all

Comment: done but same output as earlier (
            [name] => 10k.csv
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

Comment: @abhinavBruteForce have you restarted ur apache? try to output ur phpinfo() to double check ur setting.

Comment: @abhinavBruteForce If this answer resolved the issue, you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in php.ini as

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

reload apache or if it is staging environment restart apache.You will sucessfully upload increased size file. Thanks zairwolf its all your credit.